# How to convert stream to array using RxJs.toArray method without completing the subject?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to allow user to pass ids to get some filtered data. For that purpose I create a subject which allows to send an array of Guid:

```
selectedVacancies: Subject<string[]> = new Subject();
selectedVacancies.next(['a00652cd-c11e-465f-ac09-aa4d3ab056c9',
                         'f145b6a6-0a66-49d6-a2d2-eb9123061d96']);
```

I have another observable which is subscribed to this subject and waiting for data to come (availableVacancies and availableVacancyTypes are just Observable and Observable from my angular service):

```
filteredVacancyTypes: Observable<VacancyTypeModel[]>;
filteredVacancyTypes = this.selectedVacancies
     .flatMap(vacancyIds => vacancyIds)
     .filter(id => !isNullOrUndefined(id))
     .flatMap(id => this.availableVacancies.first(v => v.id === id))
     .flatMap(v => this.availableVacancyTypes.filter(vt => vt.id === v.type.id))
```

I want to accumulate the data which is filtered and return it as an array of VacancyTypeModels. I know what toArray method exists but I'm unable to use it since the subject is never getting completed (since I have to wait for another ids to be published by user)

Does any way exists to return the data as an array without completing the source?

Comment: to return it **where**? If you don't complete the observable you cannot return anything because the observable is not complete

Comment: I use filteredVacancyTypes to display using angular data binding:
`li(*ngFor="let item of (filteredVacancyTypes | async)") {{item.title}}`

Comment: you can just subscribe manually and manipulate your array as you wish...

Comment: thanks, i will use `.subscribe(vt => this.filteredVacancyTypes.push(vt));` instead of this. It seems to me what I understand Rx philosophy in incorrect way...

Comment: It's fine, it's really hard to understand it. Even the rx authors have problems with the naming etc :) Also the async pipe is good for angular marketing but it is really seldom when you can really rely on it.

Comment: If you want to accumulate stuff Martin's answer is good for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accumulating items is easy with the `scan` operator:

```
filteredVacancyTypes = this.selectedVacancies
  .scan((acc, arr) => [...acc, ...arr], [])
  .flatMap(vacancyIds => vacancyIds)
  ...
```

The `scan` emits each intermediate result. You could also use it later after all the logic you need:

```
filteredVacancyTypes = this.selectedVacancies
  .flatMap(vacancyIds => vacancyIds)
  ...
  .scan((acc, val) => [...acc, val], [])
```

Comment: This stuff works well. Thanks. But how can I erase filteredVacancyTypes 
observable before adding new data? 
Now it contains data like
`[VacancyType1, VacancyType2]` for the first run and `[VacancyType1, VacancyType2, VacancyType1, VacancyType2, VacancyType3]` when i'm trying to call next with other input parameters :(

Comment: never mind. I've used you solution to accumulate my data and created a special service which always return new observable